# How to assign a particular admin role to an Azure AD application?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I hope someone can help..

I have a registered application (TestApp3), with which I connect successfully using:
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenant -CertificateThumbprint $thumb -ApplicationId $applicationID

Now once connected, I need to assign users to a different application (TestApp2).

If I use the following command (when connected as Global Admin)

Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Application administrator"}).Objectid -RefObjectId $sp.ObjectId

This will grant the App Admin role to the application TestApp3.

So, the following will work when connected as TestApp3:
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectID -PrincipalId $user.ObjectID -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId  -Id ([Guid]::Empty)

This will add a user to the list of assigned users for the servicePrincipal TestApp2.
However, its 'scoped' across the tenant. How do I configure it so TestApp3 can only assign users for the specific app TestApp2?

Thanks..

//A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I configure it so TestApp3 can only assign users for the
> specific app TestApp2?

According to this microsoft document [***assign app owners***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-app-owners)

> Similar to application administrator, an owner has capability to
> manage many or all  azure ad configuration aspects but  for a
> specific organization application (appl registration or enterprise
> application.) they are assigned to.

***`They can do user assignments`***, SSO configuration and provisioning. Owner can even add /remove other owners and can ***`manage the applications that they own only`***.

*Add an owner using powershell cmds.*

```
Connect-AzureAD
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx3-xxx -RefObjectId xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

- `ObjectId`  > object id of the application

**References:**

1. [assign-application-owners- Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-app-roles#assign-application-owners)
2. [Add Azure AD Application as owner of another AD Application –
   LockTar’s Blog](https://www.locktar.nl/programming/powershell/add-azure-ad-application-as-owner-of-another-ad-application/)